# How to disable autocomplete and error pop-ups in an LSP, but keep the other LSP features in Neovim

Tags: lua, neovim, language-server-protocol

I am using Neovim (kickstart.nvim) and am new to programming and don't want all the words (auto complete) handed to me nor error messages/pop-ups so I could learn to deal with it myself, but I do want the other LSP feature like function definitions etc.

In more general terms I want to know how to configure (enable and disable) different options for the LSP and a list of options.

the problem is that all the things I find online are people telling you how to add them not take them away (looks like everyone wants them on but me )

---

just some information: I'm very new to programming (as I've mentioned), and don't have a lot of Lua or any complete programming knowledge. I wanted a light editor (vs code feels like too much). I was using notepad++ till now (and it was pretty good ). I wanted to try vim motions but they don't have a plug-ins for that (they have an old one only for 32-bit one and even on that is broke it ‍♂️), so I got neovim (I think it's good, because I any like to work from the terminal) and here I am .

Comment: You should consider reading `README.md`

Comment: @Tribhuwan which README.md ? on the github? I don't see where? if you could point to to where exactly, that could be great.